# Removing a string using regular expression with stringr

Tags: regex, r, stringr, jsonlite

I am trying to get rid of the term union in the following json using str_replace_all function. I tried few regular expressions but they didn't work. Any suggestions on how to get rid of the full string of "union". Here is the code.

```
 library(jsonlite)

 json<- '{"open_issues":0,"union":{"avatar_url":"https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/ed73cf7f24c091318e507d167c7b3456?d=https://a248.e.akamai.net/assets.mashups.com%2Fimages%2Fgravatars%2Fgravatar-orgs.png","gravatar_id":"ed73cf7f24c091318e507d167c7b3456","id":1556245,"login":"Toolpark","url":"https://api.mashups.com/users/Toolpark"},"owner":{"avatar_url":"https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/ed73cf7f24c091318e507d167c7b3456?d=https://a248.e.akamai.net/assets.mashups.com%2Fimages%2Fgravatars%2Fgravatar-orgs.png","gravatar_id":"ed73cf7f24c091318e507d167c7b3456","id":1556245,"login":"Toolpark","url":"https://api.mashups.com/users/Toolpark"},"private":false,"pushed_at":"2012-07-12T11:43:31Z","size":964,"ssh_url":"vit@mashups.com:Toolpark/irma.vit","svn_url":"https://mashups.com/Toolpark/irma","updated_at":"2012-07-12T11:43:31Z","url":"https://api.mashups.com/repos/Toolpark/irma","watchers":2}'

str_replace_all(json,"union[^}]*}\s*, "")
json <- fromJSON(json)
Error: '\s' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""union[^}]*}\s"
```

I am  trying to get rid of this string exactly including the coma in the end:

```
"union":{"avatar_url":"https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/ed73cf7f24c091318e507d167c7b3456?d=https://a248.e.akamai.net/assets.mashups.com%2Fimages%2Fgravatars%2Fgravatar-orgs.png","gravatar_id":"ed73cf7f24c091318e507d167c7b3456","id":1556245,"login":"Toolpark","url":"https://api.mashups.com/users/Toolpark"},
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: it looks like you are missing some quotation marks on the str_replace_all line

Comment: yeah i tried that! it didn't go through

Comment: Try `str_replace_all(json, '"union"[^}]*\\s*,', "")`.  Keep in mind that this may not work with stripping newlines between `}` and `,` (not that that's generally a concern).  Also keep in mind that if `}` is in the `union` string it won't work like you expect either.  It would make more sense to parse the JSON and then delete the `union` property.

Comment: Maybe I missed something but, why you just don't `cat(gsub("union", "", json))` ?

Comment: I didn't work either!!

Comment: Try this: sub('.*(?<=Toolpark\\/)(irma.*)','\\1',string,perl=T)

Comment: I need a general regular expression which can get rid of more strings of this nature.

Comment: I am using `code` file <- "json.json" library('tm') json <- readLines(json). And i issued the command you suggested and i am still getting the union column.

Comment: Your example works for me if I use `json <- fromJSON(gsub("union", "", json))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am guessing correct, you intend to delete the "union" element from the json line. So, why don't you change the line into json using *fromJSON* function and then try deleting the **union** element. The following code yields you a list without **union**

```
json1 <- ("your json line") 
my_list<- fromJSON(json1)   #convert into json format which gives you a list of elements
my_list["union"]<- NULL   #delete the union element
print(my_list)
```

Comment: i have a huge json file which is difficult to be copied into the .R file and i am seeking some alternative solution. Note that I don't have a valid json file and i need to make it to valid json and do the operations! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

You have been using your regex with bad syntax.. Use the following:

```
str_replace_all(json, "\"union[^}]*}\\s*,", "")
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/qT3iQ4/1)

Comment: Thank you so much! I am getting this error: Error in stri_replace_all_regex(string, pattern, replacement, vectorize_all = vec,  : 
  Syntax error in regexp pattern. (U_REGEX_RULE_SYNTAX). Not sure if it is a r package issue.